# SQL return row from first table, and then joined tables separately

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. I want to select all rows from table 1, and any rows from table 2 that share the same id. I need to return the row from table 1, and then, if they exist, separately return the joined rows of both table 1 and 2. My current code below returns the row from table 1 if there is no match in table 2. However, if a match exists in table 2 it will only return the joined rows.

```
SELECT
    table1.id,
    COALESCE(table2.name, table1.name) AS name
FROM
    table1
LEFT JOIN
    table2
ON
    table1.id = table2.id
WHERE
    table1.stock = 0
```

And here's what I'm after:

```
**Table 1**
id  | name  | stock
101 | sock  | 4
102 | hat   | 0
103 | belt  | 0

**Table 2**
id  | name
101 | banana
102 | pear
102 | apple

**Query output**
id  | name
102 | hat
102 | pear
102 | apple
103 | belt
```

Comment: table structure, sample input and desired output

Comment: Your desired output and your description seem to have nothing to do with each other.  Your description starts with returning all rows from the first table, but 101 is not in the output.

Answer (score 0):

From your output, I gather that you want something like all rows from both tables where the id in table one has a stock of 0.

```
select id, name
from table1
where stock = 0
union all
select id, name
from table2 t2
where exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.id = t2.id and t1.stock = 0);
```